# Differentiate between iOS and macCatalyst in xcconfig file

Tags: ios, xcode, xcconfig, mac-catalyst

In an xcconfig file it's possible to use `sdk` and `arch` specifiers. For example:

```
BUILD_SETTING_NAME[sdk=sdk] = value for specified sdk
BUILD_SETTING_NAME[arch=architecture] = value for specified architecture
```

How can I use this to use a different value when building for macCatalyst ("UIKit for Mac")?

Comment: Use different configurations?

Comment: @matt Yes, that would work, but only a single value needs to be different, so I was hoping I could avoid that route.

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that x86 doesn't mean simulator anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, it turns out to be easier than I thought. You can simply do this in your xcconfig file:

```
SOME_PLATFORM_DEPENDENT_VALUE = "use this on iOS";
SOME_PLATFORM_DEPENDENT_VALUE[sdk=macosx*] = "use this on macOS including macCatalyst";
```

On the first line you set the value for all platforms. On the second line you set the value for a specific SDK. The specific value takes precedence over the "general" value.

That's it! You can learn more about these different options in this [great NSHipster article](https://nshipster.com/xcconfig/).

Comment: Thanks Johannes :) I need configuration for iOS+Catalyst (iOS SDK) and another one for 'regular' macOS (Mac SDK)... Do you know if that is possible? Thanks :)

Comment: @JensSchwarzer I don't know for sure... Check out the NSHipster article. You might be able to accomplish this by combining both `sdk=` and `arch=`. I think the `arch` value would have to be `x86_64`. Otherwise using some other value that is set for your macOS target might help.

Comment: Thanks again Johannes :) I had to give up this because `macosx` kicks in for Catalyst. And I don't think I can use `arch` because macOS also runs on arm now...

Comment: @JensSchwarzer There seems to be an `IS_MACCATALYST` build variable you can use, see it mentioned here: https://steipete.com/posts/zld-a-faster-linker/